# Reading content of a shared file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to read the content of a shared file from another computer(it has a password). I searched on google how to access that file and i made my own code:

```
 Option Explicit On
 Public Class Form1
Dim file As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim readfile As Scripting.TextStream
Private Structure NETRESOURCE
    Public dwScope As UInteger
    Public dwType As UInteger
    Public dwDisplayType As UInteger
    Public dwUsage As UInteger
    Public lpLocalName As String
    Public lpRemoteName As String
    Public lpComment As String
    Public lpProvider As String
End Structure
Declare Function WNetAddConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias _
       "WNetAddConnection2A" (lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, _
       ByVal lpPassword As String, ByVal lpUserName As String, _
       ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Declare Function WNetCancelConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias _
"WNetCancelConnection2A" (ByVal lpName As String, _
ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal fForce As Long) As Long

Private Const NO_ERROR As UInteger = 0
Private Const RESOURCETYPE_DISK As UInteger = 1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '' readfile = file.OpenTextFile(Process.Start("net.exe", "use \\Reznicencu-2025\share /USER:Reznicencu Reznicencu".ToString), Scripting.IOMode.ForReading)
    ''MsgBox(readfile.ReadAll)
    Test()
End Sub



Private Sub Test()
    Dim nr As New NETRESOURCE
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK
    nr.lpRemoteName = "\\Reznicencu-2025\share"
    If WNetAddConnection2(nr, "Reznicencu", "Reznicencu", 0) <> NO_ERROR Then
        Throw New Exception("WNetAddConnection2 failed.")
    End If
    'Code to use connection here.'
    If WNetCancelConnection2("\\Reznicencu-2025\share", 0, True) <> NO_ERROR Then
        Throw New Exception("WNetCancelConnection2 failed.")
    End If
End Sub



End Class
```

I'm not sure if it's right because it tells me that " 'lpNetResource' cannot expose type 'NETRESOURCE' in namespace 'Messenger' through class 'Form1'".Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I changed something in another form. That seems to be the problem.